# Help me optimize an ActiveRecord object with too many attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, activerecord

I'm working on a app which ties to a legacy database.  The primary model is based on a stupidly large 100+ column table.  I don't know too much about the inner-workings of ActiveRecord but it seems to me that any request on this model is slowing down because it's creating objects with 100+ attributes.  Let's call this SlowModel.

Rendering pages with this model sometimes take 17 seconds on my dev computer.  Straight up mysql queries only take ~ 0.5 - 1 second.

I've managed to speed up one portion of the app by using a MySQL view that selects a subset of fields (20 or so).  We'll call this QuickModel.  Using views is OK but isn't the most portable solution.

I will likely continue to try and add this QuickModel into other parts of the site but I was wondering if anyone had other ideas in speeding up the original object.  For instance, is there a way to specify in the model what columns activerecord should just ignore and avoid building?  Maybe there are specific column types (:text??) that cause bloat in ActiveRecord objects.

Assume that columns have proper indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having a completely new QuickModel that sits to its own table... and a QuickModel has_one SlowModel?

You can use SQL to move the most-necessary data into the QuickModel table and only refer to the SlowModel using my_quick_model.slow_model when necessary.

Alternatively, you can add a "select" to the default scope (you can google "rails default scope" for more). By default it'll only fetch the reduced set - but you can ask for all attributes by passing :select => "*" if necessary.

Comment: You've hit on an interesting point.  We actually have a scope set up to return less fields but for some reason it doesn't actually seem to work.  We call this scope :stubbed

it's odd because Model.select(...) does work but when using Model.stubbed it gets overwritten somehow by subsequent operations.  That's probably just a bug somewhere in our code though.  I'd like to run some tests and see if running a reduced select is faster.

Comment: It turns out that
http://www.snowgiraffe.com/tech/327/when-to-select-and-include-your-rubies-and-rails/
is our problem with our :stubbed scope because we have a .includes in there as well.

Comment: The solution for this problem was to change .includes to .joins as shown in the second answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047833/rails-3-select-with-include

Comment: "How about having a completely new QuickModel that sits to its own table... and a QuickModel has_one SlowModel?" is also a really interesting solution, might try to implement something like that with the view we already have.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify which columns are returned in the model lookup using the :select option of the ActiveRecord lookup:

```
SlowModel.all(:select => 'id, col1, col2, col3')
```

...will load instances of SlowModel with only the specified columns populated.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what Winfield is saying, you may want to take a look at using an attribute tracker like [SlimScrooge](https://github.com/sdsykes/slim_scrooge).  The tracker attempts to fetch only the data that you're using, which reduces overhead.  It attempts to automatically do what Winfield is suggesting.

Example from the Readme:

```
# 1st request, sql is unchanged but columns accesses are recorded
Brochure Load SlimScrooged 1st time (27.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `brochures` WHERE (expires_at IS NULL)

# 2nd request, only fetch columns that were used the first time
Brochure Load SlimScrooged (4.5ms)   SELECT `brochures`.expires_at,`brochures`.operator_id,`brochures`.id FROM `brochures` WHERE (expires_at IS NULL)

# 2nd request, later in code we need another column which causes a reload of all remaining columns
Brochure Reload SlimScrooged (0.6ms) `brochures`.name,`brochures`.comment,`brochures`.image_height,`brochures`.id, `brochures`.tel,`brochures`.long_comment,`brochures`.image_name,`brochures`.image_width FROM `brochures` WHERE `brochures`.id IN ('5646','5476','4562','3456','4567','7355')

# 3rd request
Brochure Load SlimScrooged (4.5ms)   SELECT `brochures`.expires_at,`brochures`.operator_id,`brochures`.name, `brochures`.id FROM `brochures` WHERE (expires_at IS NULL)
```

Comment: That looks interesting and we might try to go that route.