# rails select with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have these code in my rails 3.2 application

```
User.includes(:profile).limit(10)
```

which select all fields from profiles table I need a way to select on specific fields from profiles table to decrease db queries 
I am using postgresql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 - select with Include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047833/rails-3-select-with-include)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you, ask for [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) method.

```
User.includes(:profile).limit(10).select(:field1, :field2)
```

**Update:**

The answer from @Hassan woudn't really work. Look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) (Eager loading section)

> Since only one table is loaded at a time, conditions or orders cannot reference tables other than the main one.

Try following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile_w_name, -> { select(:id, :name, :user_id).limit(10) }, class_name: 'Profile'
end

User.includes(:profile_w_name).first.profile_w_name
```

Don't forget to add `user_id` field, because AR will try to preload profile field.

**Update:**

I found a better solution for all above, after I saw deprecation warning that complains about eager loading and SQL snippet for references like `select("post.id, comment.post_id")`. Rails 4 required.

```
User.includes(:profile).select(:field1, :field2).references(:profile)
```

Also checkout this gist to see difference https://gist.github.com/astery/6137727

Comment: It will select from users table I want to select specific fields from profiles table

Comment: Why do you think so? Did you try the gist?

Comment: if I understand correct the 2nd update, you can do something like this? `@users = User.includes(:profile).select('user.id, user.name, profile.id, profile.something, profile.something_else').references(:profile)` ?

Comment: So this would generate two queries like these? `SELECT id, name FROM users` and `SELECT id, something, something else FROM profiles WHERE user_id IN ( user IDs here )`

Comment: @Lykos, I left a comment with debug output for you in gist.

Answer (score 9):

You're better of using something like

```
User.joins(:profile).select("users.*, profiles.field1, profiles.field2").limit(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 5 Way:** Just add a reference to the associated table name.

```
User.includes(:profile).select("users.*, profiles.field1, profiles.field2").limit(10).references(:profiles)
```

Comment: Try now.  I had left out the "." operator on the call to limit(10).  Now fixed.

Comment: Still, it doesn't work. You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400860/activerecord-includes-specify-included-columns