# rails includes query loading entire data for included models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application where I have following models.

```
BookingHotel
    has_many :hotel_picture_partners, through: :hotel_pictures
    has_many :booking_hotel_partner_details, dependent: :destroy

BookingHotelPartnerDetail
    belongs_to :booking_hotel

HotelPicturePartner
    belongs_to :hotel_picture, dependent: :destroy
```

I have a query as follows

```
@booking_hotel_partner_details = BookingHotelPartnerDetail.unscoped.select(:id, :booking_hotel_id, :partner_booking_hotel_id).includes(booking_hotel: :hotel_picture_partners)
```

This puts memory under pressure as it loads all data for included models.

Is there a way I can only load selective fields from booking_hotels & hotel_picture_partners tables ?

Also I want to get an activerecord array as response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 - select with Include?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047833/rails-3-select-with-include)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pluck` method loads only attributes, without loading whole models. check it: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck.

Try to rewrite it like this:
`BookingHotelPartnerDetail.unscoped.select('booking_hotels.id as bh_id', 'hotel_picture_partners.id as hpp_id').joins(booking_hotel: :hotel_picture_partners)`

Comment: I want to load included models but pluck will give me an array

Comment: It seems to be correct Andrey. This will not load all associated records in memory right ?

Comment: Raman M, it won't eager load it, right, you can check the SQL query generated by this AR query in Rails logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your project is probably already pretty far along, but for anyone else wanting this behaviour I've released a patch that filters columns if you have a `.select(...)` along with `.includes(...)` or `.eager_load(...)`.
It's now included in a data-related gem I maintain, **[The Brick](https://github.com/lorint/brick)**.

It works by overriding `ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency.apply_column_aliases()` **[like this](https://github.com/lorint/brick/blob/3983b99b3d068834a8d07d44b8749b46b211d41f/lib/brick.rb#L1251-L1310)**.

In order to enable this selective behaviour, add the special column name `:_brick_eager_load` as the first entry in your `.select(...)`, which turns on the filtering of columns while the aliases are being built out.  Here's an example based on your code:

```
@booking_hotel_partner_details =
  BookingHotelPartnerDetail.unscoped
                           .includes(booking_hotel: :hotel_picture_partners)
                           .select(:_brick_eager_load, :id, :partner_booking_hotel_id, 'booking_hotel.name', 'hotel_picture_partners.notes')
```

Feel free to add myraid additional columns from any table as strings in the same way as the last two sample items I put into the `.select(...)`.

Because foreign keys are essential to have everything be properly associated, they are automatically added, so you do not need to include `:booking_hotel_id` in your select list.

Hope it can save you both query time and some RAM!